# Trying to upgrade graphite and now it's not working properly

Tags: python, graphite

I've tried to update graphite from version '0.9.10' to '0.9.13' and I broke our graphite installation.

The problem is that the graph images no longer render but the tree view still works and all the old data is still there.

The trace back I get is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 99, in get_response
    request.path_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 271, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 271, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 159, in resolve
    return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 168, in _get_callback
    raise ViewDoesNotExist("Could not import %s. Error was: %s" % (mod_name, str(e)))
ViewDoesNotExist: Could not import graphite.render.views. Error was: cannot import name timezone
```

I also get the same error if I try `/dashboard`.

Python 2.7 is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I had django version 1.3.1 install when I needed 1.4.1, installing that fixed my problem.